# Is there a way to run scpecific task in google chrome/edge automatically every time I start the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I need to perform some actions everyday in google chrome or Ms edge, is there a way I can automate this?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exact tasks you want to run in the MS Edge browser? I could help you check whether it is possible to achieve or not.

Comment: You could use Microsoft Edge Web Driver to automate the Edge browser. You could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) to get detailed information. Further, it depends on what exact tasks you would like to automate. If you provide the information about those tasks then I could provide further suggestions and code examples to achieve it.